# Relation between Jacobi field and Killing field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a manifold, $X$ a vector field on $M$. 
Question: If for every point $p\in M$, there exist a neighborhood $U$, such that for any radial geodesic $\gamma$ in $U$, $X(\gamma)$ is a Jacobi field, then, must $X$ be a Killing field?

Answer (score 3):

No - Jacobi fields only preserve geodesics, not all geometry. It's easiest to see the distinction in the flat case - any continuous family of linear transformations of $\mathbb R^n$ will preserve geodesics and thus produce such an $X$, but most linear transformations are not isometries.

For an explicit counterexample, consider the radial vector field $X = x \partial_x + y \partial_y$ on the Euclidean plane $\mathbb R^2$, which is clearly not Killing. An arbitrary geodesic has the form $\gamma(t) = (a+vt,b+wt)$, along which we have $$X(\gamma(t)) = (a+vt)\partial_x + (b+wt)\partial_y.$$ Since the Christoffel symbols are vanishing, the Jacobi equation is simply $(X \circ \gamma)''(t) = 0$, which is clearly satisfied.

What you *can* conclude is that $X$ is an "infinitesimal affine transformation", i.e. its flow pulls back the Levi-Civita connection. See e.g. Chapter 13 of Lang's *Fundamentals of Differential Geometry* for some discussion of the relationship - in particular you *can* conclude $X$ is Killing if you assume $M$ is compact, by a [theorem of Yano](http://doi.org/10.2307/1969418).

Edit: addressing the comments, here's a (cumbersome) proof that for a torsion-free connection, the variation $\gamma(t,s) =  F^X_s \gamma_0(t)$ is geodesic whenever $\gamma_0$ is geodesic and $X$ is Jacobi along every geodesic. This fact about $X$ implies the "global Jacobi equation" $\nabla^2_{v,v} X = R(v,X)v$ for any vector $v.$ I use the notation $\dot \gamma$ for the vector field $D\gamma(\partial_t)$, which is the velocity vector of $\gamma_s$ when $s$ is fixed. Note that $X$ and $\dot \gamma$ commute.

$\def\n{\nabla}
\def\dg{\dot \gamma}$Applying the definition of the curvature and using $\n_X \dg = \n_\dg X$ we get $$\n_X \n_{\dg} \dg = R(X, \dg) \dg + \n_\dg \n_\dg X.$$ Using the global equation $\n^2_{\dg,\dg}X = \n_{\dot \gamma} 
 (\n_{\dot \gamma} X) - \nabla_{\nabla_{\dot \gamma} \dot \gamma} X = R(\dot \gamma,X)\dot \gamma$ we can write this as

$$\n_X(\n_{\dot \gamma} \dot \gamma) = \n_{\n_{\dot \gamma} \dot \gamma} X;$$

i.e. $A = \n_{\dot \gamma} \dot \gamma$ and $X$ commute. Since $A$ is zero along $\gamma_0$, we therefore have $$F^A_t F^X_s p = F^X_s F^A_tp = F^X_s p$$ for all $p$ on $\gamma_0$, and thus $A$ is zero on all points that can be reached by flowing along $X$ from $\gamma_0$, as desired.

Comment: thanks! what does 'Jacobi fields only preserve geodesics' specifically mean?

Comment: @user360777: a Jacobi field along a geodesic is precisely a vector field that generates a geodesic variation; so a "global Jacobi field" like your $X$ is precisely a vector field whose small-time flow sends geodesics to geodesics: for all $t\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ the flow map $F^X_t$ is an affine transformation, meaning it sends geodesics to geodesics, or equivalently $({F^X_t}^*) \nabla = \nabla$. That is, it's exactly the same situation as Killing fields, but preserving $\nabla$ instead of $g$.

Comment: i'm a little confused, let $\gamma(s)$ be a geodesic, $\gamma_t(s)=F^X_t(\gamma(s))$, then $X(\gamma(s))=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0}\gamma_t(s)$, but why $\gamma_t$ are geodesics?

Comment: @user360777: you're right, it's nontrivial - I've added this result to my answer.

Comment: Anyway, after all that I think we've gotten off track - the key point I was trying to make is that we can define all the notions used in your question (geodesics and Jacobi fields) in terms of the connection alone, and thus it's too much to hope that you get a symmetry of the metric, unless you're in a setting where every symmetry of the connection is also a symmetry of the metric.